# $_SESSION wont work without filename in URL?

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm currently working on a site where I'm trying to make use of the session variables.

I have a controller script (*index.php*) that begins with `session_start();` and has two different HTML files included within `if` statements. Everything works all groovy when I go to `/quote/index.php`, the session variables that I've set are echoed on the page as expected, however if I remove '`index.php`*' from the URL so it points to just `/quote` the page loads however none of the session variables show up.

I'm not using `session_destroy` anywhere in my scripts and the session variables aren't echoing '`0`' so I'm fairly sure they aren't being unset, it seems as though they are just ignored without the filename in the URL!

Any insight as to why this is occuring would be awesome,
Thanks

/quote/index.php (with extraneous bits removed):

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['form']))
    {
include 'form.html.php';
exit();
    }
if (isset($_GET['fetchquote'])) 
    {
    $width = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['width']);
    $height = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['height']);
    $_SESSION['height'] = $height;
    $_SESSION['width'] = $width;
    }
include 'quote.html.php';
?>
```

The session variables are echoed in quote.html.php

Comment: Make sure your additional html files on root aren't named "index.html" or "index.htm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are the two file names?
seems that one of the file that you are including is named index.html and resides in the mysite.com/quote/ itself. And if I am not wrong, if in a directory there are index.html and index.php then the index.html is loaded by default unless the file is explicitly specified in the url. So it seems in your case when you are not specifying the index.php explicitly,the index.html is being loaded.Of course this is the case only if there is an index.html there in the directory.

Comment: Just edited my question to contain the code, I was hoping what you described would be the case but alas, nope! Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are also using `session_start()` at the top of the PHP pages where you want to echo the session variable.  And make sure index.php is the only index in your root.

You are checking if an option is set via the GET method.  Where is your form using the GET method?

Post your entire script and you'll get much better answers.

Answer (score 0):

This has probably something to do with the validity scope of the session ID cookie. Because if the [cookie path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path) is set to `/quote/`, the cookie will only be available in `/quote/` and beyond.